# JBOSS EAP7 and eclipse, HTTP 403 Forbidden::The website declined to show this webpage

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am new to JBOSS EAP and trying to run a basic web application on this.Below is the process I did:

1. Downloaded and installed JBOSS EAP 7
2. Downloaded Eclipse mars.
3. Downloaded jdk 1.8
4. JAVA_HOME set in the env variable and java path variable set.
5. Open eclipse
6. Configuration JBOSS EAP server in eclipse
   a. Define a new Server
   b. Select Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7.x
       Server's host name = localhost
       Server Name = Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.x
   c.Clicked on next button and finish.
   7.Right click and started the server ( server started successfully).
7. I am able to open (http://localhost:8080/), without any issue.
8. Creating Web Application in eclipse
   a. Open New Project => Dynamic web Project
   b. Project name given : HelloApp
   c. I didn't select checkbox for "Generate web.xml  deployment descriptor".
   d. Create new HTML file (Index.html), inside HelloApp/WebContent folder
   e. Added Hello in the body part of the HTML.
9. Running HelloApp Project.
   a. Right Click and select run as sever
   b. Select Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.x
   c. Adding HelloApp to configured tab.
   d. Finish button

Below is the jboss logs:

```
    13:29:11,462 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final-redhat-1
    13:29:11,887 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final-redhat-1
    13:29:12,019 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.2.Final-redhat-1) starting
    13:29:14,178 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found MyWebApp.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called MyWebApp.war.dodeploy
    13:29:14,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
    13:29:14,326 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.3.6.Final-redhat-1
    13:29:14,343 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.6.Final-redhat-1
    13:29:14,410 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
    13:29:14,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
    13:29:14,434 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
    13:29:14,434 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
    13:29:14,438 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
    13:29:14,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
    13:29:14,456 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
    13:29:14,504 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final-redhat-1
    13:29:14,551 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
    13:29:14,687 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.3.Final-redhat-1)
    13:29:14,690 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.21.Final-redhat-1 starting
    13:29:14,694 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.3.21.Final-redhat-1 starting
    13:29:14,710 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
    13:29:14,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
    13:29:14,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
    13:29:15,030 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\AVIKUMAR\JBOSS-EAP-7.0.0/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
    13:29:15,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
    13:29:15,184 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
    13:29:15,489 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
    13:29:15,498 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
    13:29:15,500 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.18.Final-redhat-1
    13:29:15,588 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
    13:29:15,729 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\AVIKUMAR\JBOSS-EAP-7.0.0\standalone\deployments
    13:29:15,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "MyWebApp.war" (runtime-name: "MyWebApp.war")
    13:29:16,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    13:29:16,250 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.2.Final-redhat-1
    13:29:16,463 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.3.SP1-redhat-1 (Apache CXF 3.1.4.redhat-1) 
    13:29:17,751 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /MyWebApp
    13:29:17,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "MyWebApp.war" (runtime-name : "MyWebApp.war")
    13:29:18,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    13:29:18,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    13:29:18,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started in 7216ms - Started 336 of 627 services (382 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
    19:36:12,928 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found HelloApp.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called HelloApp.war.dodeploy
    19:36:12,953 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "HelloApp.war" (runtime-name: "HelloApp.war")
    19:36:13,048 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /HelloApp
    19:36:13,134 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "HelloApp.war" (runtime-name : "HelloApp.war")
```

11. In the eclipse browser getting below error

    ```
    The website declined to show this webpage.

    More information   
    This error (HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that this program was able to connect to the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage.
    ```

Answer (score 0):

See the quickstart example below follow step by step process:

http://www.jboss.org/quickstarts/eap/helloworld/